# How to apply style on first child of multilevel recursive classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im trying to apply a style only on the first grand child of the main container.
The structure looks like this.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.main {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container.main .item>* {
  border-color: red;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1px 1px 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="item">

        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the first child to be yellow and the last child to be dotted.
How can I do this?
As you can see each child could be some level deep in different container.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between a child (`a > b`) and decedent (`a b`). In your code, the only child of `.container.main` is `.container.main > .container`.

Comment: Ok i got that. I want the first .item to be effected no matter how deep. and Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this with only CSS due to the differing levels. However, using a combination of CSS and javascript:

```css
.item.first { /* some style */ }
.item.last { /* some other style */ }
```

```js
const root = document.querySelector('.container.main');
const items = root.querySelectorAll('.item');
items[0].classList.add('first');
items[items.length-1].classList.add('last');
```